# Cannot run go binary as systemctl daemon

Tags: go, daemon, systemd

I have a go web app which is on the path  `/home/me/go/src/myapp`.
When I run the executable using `./myapp` on bash terminal, it works fine.
However this requires an open terminal to continue running, which is not practial so I tried to make a systemd daemon on my Debian server's `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service` like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=MyApp Daemon
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
User= me
Group=www-data
ExecStart=/home/me/go/src/myapp/myapp
TimeoutStopSec=300
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have enabled and started the daemon:

```
systemctl enable myapp
```

Start it:

```
systemctl start myapp
```

However it fails to run the daemn, and I get this error:

```
# systemctl status myapp
● myapp.service - MyApp Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-17 05:42:18 CDT; 4s ago
  Process: 19058 ExecStart=/home/me/go/src/myapp/myapp (code=exited, status=127)
 Main PID: 19058 (code=exited, status=127)
      CPU: 2ms
 Jul 17 05:42:18 front systemd[1]: Started Myapp Daemon.
Jul 17 05:42:18 front systemd[1]: myapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Jul 17 05:42:18 front systemd[1]: myapp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 17 05:42:18 front systemd[1]: myapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm wondering what could be wrong and how should I fix it?

Comment: When this happens, do you see any output in `journalctl -xe`? You usually don't have to do anything special other than checking execuable permissions on the file.

Comment: Yes I get this in the log `pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jul 17 06:23:13 front sshd[19998]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=20`

Comment: does user me exists?

Comment: of course. That's me!

Comment: try `sudo journalctl -f -u myapp.service`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of trial and error this config worked for me:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sai Go webapp Daemon
#After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Type=simple
User= me
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/me/go/src/myapp/
ExecStart=/home/me/go/src/myapp/myapp
TimeoutStopSec=300
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Apparently `WorkingDirectory` was necessary.